# How can I rollback to previous theme/subtheme or disable last used theme by using text editor only?

Tags: theming

I get a broken page; both the backend and frontend are not loading.

I'm guessing I made a mistake **while configuring a bootstrap subtheme**/starterkit (using a combination of [method 1](https://drupal.org/node/1978010) from the README file and a [youtube tutorial](http://youtu.be/0tswtupcL1Q) on activating and modifying subthemes)

Right after activating it I got a "500 Server error."

I was able to load the page by replacing the modified files with the original files, but that kinda threw all previous work to the trash (I guess I can live with that), but it would still be nice to know how to manually change theme by modifying the code directly with text editor, so in the future we all can benefit from this knowledge.

Comment: This should help you out: https://drupal.org/node/200774

Comment: @DomDay I thinks that's answer, you can add that as an answer.

Comment: @DomDay just don't make it "link only answer" ;)

Comment: I'm not sure 20 seconds on google and a minute reviewing a page merits 15 rep, but thanks for the thought : ]

Comment: I could't find it, and I did google for about half an hour. So yes, I believe it does deserve rep @dom-day, also, unanswered questions are bad for the community.